# Are there any possible way of making it impossible for website administrator to retrieve a password from a user?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

I'm creating a website and I'm afraid that my friends are afraid of that I know all the passwords.

So my question are there any possible way of making it impossible for me to retrieve a password of some random user. Hashing  is not an option, because I can still get the password before hashing. My web app is written in PHP and if there is one solution to this problem I would like to hear it.

Comment: Have your friends even expressed concern? You said you're afraid that they would be afraid, but if the initial fear is not there, then I wouldn't worry about it. As Micheal said, it really is a trust issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the password hashed in [Javascript](http://anmar.eu.org/projects/jssha2/) on the client side, before it arrives at the server. But then you would of course have to hash+salt it **again** on the server side.

You could also hand off authentication to another method, like Facebook Connect or OpenID.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing but then i saw the FB Connect thing and i was like wow.

Comment: +1 This is probably the "best" solution, although it is technically only exchanging one password with another (the hashed PW is still only a password). It does make the _original_ password unreadable, however, which is the most important thing if one has "trust issues". If someone uses the same PW elsewhere, it is not compromised. Apart from that, the site owner can access all data on the server anyway (being the root user), he does not need a user password, so there is no issue here.

Comment: If your friends are technically aware, they will want you to salt the hash with a strong random value, to be more secure against rainbow tables, even if the hash is calculated on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

you could use oauth similar to how stackoverflow works, so they can authenticate with their google/facebook/etc login